# Modeling XML requests and responses for Google Sheets API?

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb, google-sheets-api, wadl

I want to add the ability to update rows in a Google Spreadsheet to my web app. Looks like [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets) is the way to go. It's a RESTful web service that's primarily XML driven. I want to model the XML requests and responses as Java objects (unmarshal/marshal via JAXB). However, I'm not able to find any WADL or XSD files describing them. Do they exist? Is there a clever way to discover them?

If they do not exist, what's a good way to generate them? Run sample xml responses through a xml-to-xsd tool and then let JAXB create the Java classes?

Note: Google provides a Java client library, but I'd like to avoid introducing further dependencies into the project. My use cases seems simple enough to not need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging about, I was not able to find any WADL/XSD files describing the service, requests and responses. The closest find was discovering Google Sheets API is based on Atom feed format (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom). But running its XSD through JAXB generated so much extra stuff I abandoned that route.

I wrote a simple XSD to meet my Java XML model requirements. These models were enough to be able to read and add/update rows in a worksheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.1">

<xs:element name="feed">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="GoogleSheetFeed" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="entry" type="GoogleSheetFeedEntry" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="entry" type="GoogleSheetFeedEntry" />

<xs:complexType name="GoogleSheetFeedEntry">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="link">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="rel" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```